# How to keep the indentations when using reformat of CSS in PhpStorm?

Tags: css, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I use BEM-style naming of CSS-classes.

```
.b-ajax-window-header {
    display : flex;
}

    .b-ajax-window-header__left {
        margin-right : 20px;
    }

    .b-ajax-window-header__right {
        margin-left : auto;
    }
```

But when I use «Reformat Code» in PhpStorm the second and third CSS instructions are losing their indentations.

```
.b-ajax-window-header {
    display : flex;
}

.b-ajax-window-header__left {
    margin-right : 20px;
}

.b-ajax-window-header__right {
    margin-left : auto;
}
```

I've looked for setting to stop this, but I didn't find anything. Could you help me, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such setting.

This ticket seems relevant: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26136 -- watch it (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

**P.S.** If you need some sort of indenting/grouping ... why not use Less/Sass that has it? Less code to be written (no need to repeat `.b-ajax-window-header` 3 times). It will also have grouping in Structure panel.

You need it for source reading, right? Final compiled CSS is not important here (how it will be formatted); plus minification later...

Comment: Thank you. I've done everything you said (star/vote/comment).

Comment: I like full names of classes for better searching. So I don't use Sass and others.